# Visualforce PDF not rendering some of the polish characters (Urgent)

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I have generated a pdf using visualforce. In generated pdf some of the characters are not getting displayed.in word "wiadomości", this "ś" is not getting displayed.

i tried by puttiong ascii characters for missing polish characters still the problem persists.

Also added meta tag.
Any help is highly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution.. :) 
I needed to change the font of the document in body tag.

in this link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm
they have stated as--- “**Arial Unicode MS**” is the only font supported for extended character sets that include multibyte characters.